# java tensorflow reset_default_graph

Tags: java, tensorflow

I am using the tensorflow java API.

In Python, I can reset the default graph via:

tf.reset_default_graph

I can't find the corresponding function in the java api. (I've searched through the JavaDoc on Tensorflow.org + grepped through the source code on github.)

Question: is there a way to reset the default graph in java?

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of a "default graph" in Java. The `Graph` object is explicitly provided to all APIs that operate on graphs. For example, in [`LabelImage.java`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d5b76169e8e05b69c21ad533579511943429461/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java#L184) operations are added to the graph using [`Graph.opBuilder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Graph.html#opBuilder).

This is different from Python where there is an implicit graph, so when you use `tf.constant(1.)`, the `Graph` isn't provided to the function adding the operation, it uses the "default".

Long story short: There is no `tf.reset_default_graph` equivalent as there is no notion of a "default" graph.

Hope that helps.